# Plugin Loader in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, plugins

I want to be able to load usergenrerated plugins into my Typescript application like it's possible in both java or php, my idea is to provide a Plugin Class the user has to extend in his plugin to work handle all the lifecycle events. When working with this I experienced some issues when loading already compiled js files because the class did no longer work correctly so I think I have to recompile the entire code before execution?

my idea:

```
readdirSync(process.cwd(), {withFileTypes: true}).filter(dirent => dirent.isDirectory()).map(dirent => {
   if (existsSync(`${process.cwd()}/${dirent.name}/plugin.js`)) {
      const plugin = require(`${process.cwd()}/${dirent.name}/plugin.js`);
      console.log(plugin instanceof Plugin); // false
   }
});
```

Comment: Are you loading user generated plugins at runtime or compile time? If you're loading at compile time, you can create a Javascript module https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules and import / require it. If you're loading the plugin at runtime you should define an api and compile your plugin to JS before load time.

Comment: when I export a class in typescript, compile it and load the compiled JS file at runtime i'm not able to instantiate the class, also I cannot access any of the of the other exported variables, see my idea in the original post